# Prevent libcurl from sending FTP LIST command

Tags: libcurl

When connecting to a server and sending a specific QUOTE command libcurl(7.29.0) appears to be requesting a directory listing even though I do not want this.
This is the response I get back which indicates after the MDTM command was sent libcurl then sends a LIST command which I do not want.  How do I prevent it from sending LIST?

```
* Request has same path as previous transfer
> MDTM fileName
< 213 20130324223404
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||x|)
*   Trying ip...
* Connecting to ip (ip) port x
> LIST
< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
```

Portion of curl session code (I am reusing a curl handle here that previously changed the remote directory to where fileName was and get a directory listing for other purposes):

```
    headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "MDTM fileName");
    curl_easy_setopt(curlSession, CURLOPT_QUOTE, headers);       
    curl_easy_setopt(curlSession, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, &fileModResponse);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curlSession);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the libcurl source and found the answer.  Specifying the CURLOPT_NOBODY option prevents it from sending the FTP LIST command.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlSession, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
```